# Code for hide the soft keyboard is not working after selection of default menu in edit text in Android

Tags: android, keyboard, hide, android-softkeyboard

My code for hiding the soft keyboard is not working. After selection of default menu populated in long press in edit text the code for hide keyboard is not working. I tried lots of code for hiding that keyboard.

It is working in emulator but not working in some devices.

Answer (score 0):

Some keyboards behave differently, try changing the keyboard on the device and see if it changes it's behavior

Comment: yes i tried it but no use...it is not working in some mobiles like samsung galaxy ace...